# Javascript/Jquery get image actual z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to get an image's `z-index`. The problem is the customer is allowed to add css to the site so the z-index could be modified by tag, class, id, title, etc.

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var imgLength = imgs.length;
for (var i = 0; i < imgLength; i++)
{
    var zindex=document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(imgs[i],null).getPropertyValue("z-index");
    if (zindex > 1)
    {
        //correct issue here.
    }
}
```

This code only returns the style attached to the tag img. What if the customer attaced the `z-index` in some other way. In my code it doesn't tell me if the `z-index` is in custom css `img[title='image file']`. I don't care about parent like a div.

Answer (score 0):

*"This code only returns the style attaced to the tag img. What if the customer attached the z-index in some other way."*

`getComputedStyle` detects the result, it doesn't matter, which way was used to attach the style. If element has property, you can get it via `getComputedStyle(element[, pseudo])`.